# function call: using reference guaranteed to not cause relocation?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

When passing a vector to a function by reference, is the *function call* ***guaranteed to preserve validity of pointers to elements*** of the vector?

It is assumed that *inside the function*, no action is taken that might cause relocation of the vector, e.g. `push_back()`.

example:

```
int* fun(vector<int> &w) {
    return &w[10];
}

vector<int> v( /* filled with 100 random elements */ )
int *p = &v[10];
int *q = fun(v); // return pointer to v[10] element via fun()
int *r = &v[10];

bool t1 = (p == q) && (*p == *q); // always guaranteed to be true??
bool t2 = (p == r) && (*p == *r); // always guaranteed to be true??
```

although it would seem like a no-brainer to affirm, that yes, of course the *function call itself* will not invalidate pointers to elements of the vector (neither inside nor outside the function) i have been investigating this question without having been able to find a definitive answer.

the question can also be formulated as: is a function call, using "vector by reference" (as in the example), ***guaranteed*** to not cause the vector and it's elements to be relocated?

a more generalised question would be: for any kind of object or container `X`: is a function call using reference to `X` ***guaranteed to not cause relocation of `X` or any of it's constituents***?

Comment: not quite clear what makes you think there would be a potential problem. Would you ask the same for a `const int* fun(const vector<int>&w)` ?

Comment: Things can't magically happen to a reference if no mutating operation has been called on it. Vectors only relocate data in explicit circumstances, like increasing the size or erasing elements that aren't at the end.

Comment: If you don't add to or remove from the vector, its storage will not be reallocated. Note that the object itself can never move. In your example, `int *q = fun(v);` is exactly the same as `int *q = &v[10];`.

Comment: it all depends on what the function does with the reference. Another alternative for the same "problem" is to inline all the function. Would you still ask the same when in your code I replace `int *q = fun(v);` with `int *q = &w[10];` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 i think there should not be a problem, im just intrigued as to if the language guarantees that the compiler is not free to do some relocation, eg. to optimize code. i could far-fetchedly imagine a list being compacted to allow for vector-like traversal...

Comment: reallocate a vector when there is no need to is not an optimization ;). There are iterator invalidation rules. If something is not explicitly listed then iterator have to stay valid

Comment: @NathanOliver uh, changed that, thx!

Comment: do you have a real problem at hand or is this merely academical? The latter is no problem per se, but it is not clear what your doubts are based on or what you are looking for as answer. Are you looking for quotes from the standard?

Comment: All operations that can possibly invalidate pointers, references and iterators are [listed in the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/vector).

Comment: @idclev463035818 i have a lot of code that relies on this guarantee. i never imagined it could be a problem until a gnome of doubt sneaked up upon me and i could not google a definite answer. found (n. ' pronouns' gave me) that answer (https://eel.is/c++draft/vector), so great. also along the way i learned something about "reasonable assumptions", at least in c++. thx